# Can't transmit with SPI (stm32h743). Configuration issue

Tags: stm32, spi

I am trying to code the stm32h743 for spi communication and i can't seem to transmit. I am using PA5 as SCK and PD7 as MOSI. I read the procedure required that is in the reference manual (49.4.9 [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099.pdf) ) and wrote the code below but it doesn't transmit 0x3 (checked with oscilloscope).

```
    RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;   // clock enable for gpio A,B,D
    RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIODEN;          
    RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOBEN;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;   // enable SPI clock

    GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER5;   // enable alternate functions for gpioa and d
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1;  // 0b10 for alternate function, (PIN5)
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (0x05 << 5 * 4);      //  AF5 for SPI which is 0101 (it's a 4bit variation)

    GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER6;  // PIN6
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1;
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (0x05 << 6 * 4);

   GPIOD->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER7;  // PIN7
   GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1;
   GPIOD->AFR[0] |= (0x05 << 7 * 4);

   SPI1->CFG1=(7u << SPI_CFG1_DSIZE_Pos);  // 8bit data size
   SPI1->CFG2|=SPI_CFG2_MASTER ;  // master mode
   SPI1->CR1|=SPI_CR1_SPE;           // spi enable
   SPI1->CR1|=SPI_CR1_CSTART;        // transfer start
 *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->TXDR = 0x3;
```

I am obviously missing some configuration settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use magic numbers. You have human readable definitions in the CMSIS header files provided by the STM. Do now waste our time. Some another errors `&= ~(0xF << 20) & ~(0xF << 24);` => `&= ~((0xF << 20) | (0xF << 24));` I will not "decode" the magic numeric values

Comment: I am asking whether i am missing any additional configuration (ie am i missing any other steps?). I have added explanation to the "magic numbers" and you should expect them to be correct as i double checked before posting.

Comment: So do not expect any help. Respect our time. Rewrite the question using the human readable symbols - then we can help. And rewrite wrong bitwise operations as they do something different than you think

Comment: What are the human readable symbols? Numbers in hex? I don't see why you can't help and i think i am being reasonable.

Comment: `DMA1_Channel1 -> CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_EN | (0b10 << DMA_CCR_MSIZE_Pos) | (0b10 << DMA_CCR_PSIZE_Pos) | DMA_CCR_TEIE | (DMA_CCR_PL_Msk);` an example of the human readable symbols. You havetham all in the STM CMSIS headers. Download include and use

Comment: You need to force compiler to use byte wide instructions when you want to read or write the data register `*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->TXDR    = 0x3;`

Comment: When you come back to this code in a week or a month will you know what `GPIOD->AFR[0] |= (0x5 << 28);` does, other than setting bits 28 and 30 of `GPIOD->AFR`? the header has nice defines available to make it intelligible for a human.

Comment: Ok, i'll have to look into that. Every tutorial i came across had it the way i wrote it, which is why i wrote it that way.

Comment: @nurofen do not use this tutorial.

Comment: I made some changes to the original post. I hope it's more readable now.